# Is there any difference between 'type of message' vs 'messagetype'?

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality

I have seen many times with non English speaking people the use of this expressions, but I don't know whether there is any difference.

- Type of message
- Message type (or Messagetype)

Is there any difference in meaning or can we use them without any distinction?

Comment: Is is unclear (*seen* vs *indistinctly*) whether they are speaking or writing, but I would write two words: message type.

Comment: Only write `messagetype` when computer coding.  Otherwise write "message type" or "type of message".

Comment: I think you mean "without any distinction", not "indistinctly". The latter word typically means vague or hard to distinguish.

Comment: *I have seen many times* - then could you please give an example sentence?

Comment: I too am interested where you have seen **messagetype** used in written English (aside from coding). As a native speaker, I have never seen this.

Comment: Yes. _messagetype_ is computerspeak for _type of message_. Like saying _ain't_ or calling some action _inappropriate_, its use marks the user as a member of a particular social group, which they expect their addressee(s) to notice. There is no difference in meaning, only in pragmatics.

Comment: Message-type sounds like a class unlike type of message which sounds like a sample.